# Replacing Windows Explorer With Third Party Tool

Tags: windows, windows-vista, file-management

How would I go about replacing Windows Explorer with a third party tool such as TotalCommander, explorer++, etc?

I would like to have one of those load instead of win explorer when I type "C:\directoryName" into the run window. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a comment on the first LifeHacker link,

#### How to make x² your default folder application

As part of the installation process, x² adds "open with xplorer2" in the context menu for
filesystem folders.

If you want to have this the default action (so that folders always open in x2 when you click on
them) then make sure this is the default verb, either using Folder Options ("file folder" type) or
editing the registry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell]
@="open_x2"
```

If you want some slightly different command line options, you can add any of the supported
options by editing the following registry key:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\open\command]
@="C:\Program files\zabkat\xplorer2\xplorer2_UC.exe" /T /1 "%1"
```

Notes:

1. Please check your installation folder first: Your installation path may be different.
   Secondly, your executable may be called `xplorer2.exe`, if it is the non-Unicode version.
2. Note that `"%1"` is required (including the quotation marks), and is replaced by the folder path you are trying to open.
3. The `/T` switch causes no tabs to be restored and the `/1` switch puts x² in single pane mode. (You do not have to use these switches, but they make sense).

*(The above are from xplorer2 user manual)*

Comment: Thanks Judah. I guess I thought the directions for the replacement were on the lifehacker article :)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Control Panel -> Folder Options And go to the File Types tab. You can go to the "Folder" file type (with "(NONE)" as the extension). Go to Advanced, create a new action that uses your program (I tried it with FreeCommander). Make sure you set it as default.

That should do it.